# Instead of dealing damage directly kills (unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a small problem.

I have 2 scripts:

1. This is the Enemy (Enemy)
2. This is Bullet (bullet)

What is the problem itself?

When dealing damage to the enemy, I do not take a certain number of lives, and the enemy immediately dies from a single shot.
I can not understand why he dies from a single shot. When I put him to do damage to kill ....
Please help.
Sorry for my bad english.

Bullet - script (use Method Damage() , HitTarget()).
The method may have a problem Damage() -  i don't know.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class bullet : MonoBehaviour {

private Transform target;
public GameObject impactEffect;
public float speed  = 70f;
public int damage = 50;
public void Seek(Transform itarget)
{
    target = itarget;

}




// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (target == null)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
    }
    Vector3 diraction = target.position - transform.position;
    float distanceframe = speed *Time.deltaTime;
    if(diraction.magnitude <= distanceframe)
    {
        HiTarget();
        return;
    }
    transform.Translate(diraction.normalized * distanceframe, Space.World);
    transform.LookAt(target);
}
void HiTarget()
{
    GameObject effect = (GameObject)Instantiate(impactEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    Destroy(effect, 1f);

    Damage(target);
   // Destroy(gameObject);
}
void Damage(Transform enemy)
{
    Enemy e = enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>();
    if (e != null)
    {
        e.TakeDamage(damage);
    }


    //Destroy(enemy.gameObject);
}
}
```

Enemy - script (use method TakeDamage() , Die() )

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed = 10f;

private int health;
public int startHealth = 100;
private bool isDead = false;

private Transform target;
private int waveWayPointIndex = 0;

void Start()
{
    health = startHealth;
    target = Waypoints.waypoint[0];
}

public void TakeDamage(int amount)
{
    health -= amount;
    if (health <= 0 && !isDead)
    {
        Die();
    }


}
void Die()
{
    isDead = true;
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
void Update()
{

    Vector3 diraction = target.position - transform.position; //от одной 
    позиции мы поворачиваемся к другой 
    transform.Translate(diraction.normalized * speed * 
Time.deltaTime,Space.World); // переводим со скоростью

    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position,target.position)<= 0.4f) 
    {
        NextWayPoint();
    }
}

void NextWayPoint()
{
    if(waveWayPointIndex >= Waypoints.waypoint.Length - 1 )
    {
        EndPath();
        return;
    }
    waveWayPointIndex++;
    target = Waypoints.waypoint[waveWayPointIndex];
}
void EndPath()
{
    PlayerStat.Lives--;
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
}
```

---

I'm more inclined to an error in the Bullet script ...

Comment: Are you able to debug this script in Unity with the game running? If so, set a break point on `TakeDamage`. What is the value of `health` and `amount` when `TakeDamage` is called?

Comment: Seems like you'd want to destroy the bullet object after HiTarget is called, otherwise you'll be dealing constant damage.

Answer (score 2):

because you are applying the damage in `Update` by calling `HiTarget` which calls `Damage` so it is getting called each `frame`and your enemy dies fast.
you can set a `boolean` to see if the function is already called or not,if it is not called then before calling it set the boolean to true then call it, like this it will only be called once.
 it is not the best approach, but it will solve your problem.

```
  int called=false;
    void Update () {
        if (target == null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
                return;
        }
        if(!called){    
          checkForTarget()
        }
    }
    void checkForTarget(){
    Vector3 diraction = target.position - transform.position;
        float distanceframe = speed *Time.deltaTime;
        if(diraction.magnitude <= distanceframe)
        {
            called = true;
            HiTarget();
            return;
        }
        transform.Translate(diraction.normalized * distanceframe, Space.World);
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
```

Comment: the `called = true;` must be inside the `if` statement, I have edited my answer. check the new one

Comment: Thank, i find my issue

Comment: Damage(target);
 Destroy(gameObject);

Comment: after damage, me need was destroy object